# caret: Error in ctrfn(levels(x), contrasts = contrasts)

Tags: r, r-caret

Anybody have any ideas? If you need me to provide any more information, just let me know.

```
gbmFit2 <- train(SalePrice ~ .,
                  data = train,
                  na.action = na.pass,
                  method = "gbm", 
                  # preProcess = c( "knnImpute", "zv", "nzv", "YeoJohnson"),
                  trControl = fitControl,
                  ## This last option is actually one
                  ## for gbm() that passes through
                  verbose = TRUE)
```

> Error in ctrfn(levels(x), contrasts = contrasts) : orthogonal
>   polynomials cannot be represented accurately enough for 111 degrees of
>   freedom

Comment: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and make your code reproducible for us

Comment: You probably have many levels of ordered factors in your train set. Am I correct?

Comment: @missuse, yes I had many levels but I've solved the problem. Thank you for replying.

Comment: @Display_name_placeholder I'm am also running into this error.  Please post the solution.